# How to set auto scrolling on one side of the page, using class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html, which divides the page into left and right side. The left side should auto scroll down, while the right side is not moving. I've achieved this, and the auto scrolling also worked, while there was only one side. But now my javascript is not working, and I don't know how to modify it, to select just the left side of the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row wrapper">
        <div class="col-8 left-side">
            <p class="dream-id">asd</p>
            <p class="dream-body">asd</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 right-side">
            <button class="about-button">?</button>
            <button class="add-button">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-side {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.right-side {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: -100px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  will-change: overflow;
}

.left-side,
.right-side {
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: .5rem;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.left-side::-webkit-scrollbar,
.right-side::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    startScrollDown();
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    goToTop();
});

function startScrollDown() {
    scroll = setInterval(function(){ window.scrollBy(0, 1); }, 15);
}

function goToTop() {
    $(document).scrollTop(0);
}
```

Since `window.scrollBy()` is not good for this now, I have no idea how to approach this.

EDIT:

So I've found solutions, but these seems to start slowly, then speeding up. But I need the same speed, since people should be able to read the text:

```
function startScrollDown() {

    let leftSide = $('.left-side');

    leftSide.stop().animate({
        scrollTop: leftSide[0].scrollHeight
    }, 120000);
}
```

Comment: can you create a working code snippet because its little bit confusing for me to understand what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri I have to sides on my page, left and right. Right is not moving, but left contains a long text, which should be scrolling down (moving up like in star wars) automatically. So inside the left-side div the text should move up.

Comment: but you have added the `scrollBy` function for the window and not your particular left element.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri I know, that is the part I want to modify. Simply adding the element is not working